# replacement command unless condition

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am doing some data cleaning and I need to run a bash script that basically does:

- Replace every : with `":"`

I did this with `sed -i -e 's/:/":"/g'` filename

The problem is that this must be done for every occurrence in a line unless it is a time data.

For example, if my line is

```
VolumeId:vol-c29a6e96, Size:8, timestamp:Thu Jan 09 13:44:02 UTC
```

I want this to be

```
VolumeId":"vol-c29a6e96, Size":"8, timestamp":"Thu Jan 09 13:44:02 UTC
```

so I don't want the sed command to be applied everytime the data is of the form digit:digit
How can I do this? (No need to be necessary a sed command)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another perl command,

```
$ perl -pe 's/\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(*SKIP)(*F)|:/":"/g' file
VolumeId":"vol-c29a6e96, Size":"8, timestamp":"Thu Jan 09 13:44:02 UTC
```

This `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(*SKIP)(*F)|:` would totally skips all the timestamp strings and matches `:` from the remaining strings. Just replacing the matched `:` with `":"`, will give you the desired output.

Comment: +1 with reservations for relying on experimental features of perl regexes

Answer (score 0):

Since you're open for non sed option here is one option using `perl` (due to lookahead support):

```
s='VolumeId:vol-c29a6e96, Size:8, timestamp:Thu Jan 09 13:44:02 UTC'
perl -pe 's/(?<=\D):|:(?=\D)/":"/g' <<< "$s"
VolumeId":"vol-c29a6e96, Size":"8, timestamp":"Thu Jan 09 13:44:02 UTC
```

Answer (score 0):

a sed answer: change the colons in a timestamp to some other character, replace all colons, then restore the colons in timestamps

```
echo "VolumeId:vol-c29a6e96, Size:18, timestamp:Thu Jan 09 13:44:02 UTC" | 
sed -r '
    s/([[:digit:]]{2}):([[:digit:]]{2}):([[:digit:]]{2})/\1T\2T\3/g
    s/:/":"/g
    s/([[:digit:]]{2})T([[:digit:]]{2})T([[:digit:]]{2})/\1:\2:\3/g
'
```

```
VolumeId":"vol-c29a6e96, Size":"18, timestamp":"Thu Jan 09 13:44:02 UTC
```